# Width in new website >100%

Tags: html, css, width, zurb-foundation

Hello I am curious as to if someone can help with this problem. I am creating a onepage design website. And the problem seems to be that in my css (strecth2 class). The header should be fixed and span the 100% of screen; however the stretch class is pushing the entire webpage to thr right by an additional 20%.

I am using foundation 5 and was trying to get 5 evenly spaced columns. Here's my HTML the described problem.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="stretch-2">
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-2 columns">5</div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-2 columns">6</div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-2 columns">7</div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-2 columns">8</div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-2 columns end">9</div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.stretch-2 {
    width: 120%;
}

.row {
    max-width: 80em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
```

And the Foundation 5 CSS:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 62.5em;
  *zoom: 1; 
}
```

Comment: the width 120% is added by you or given by Foundation?

Comment: Well you are setting it as `width: 120%;`.... should that not be `width: 100%;`

Comment: I have added the class, to try and make an evenly spaced 5 column row, Foundation uses 12 column grid. I know the probably is due to this, but I can't seem to figure out if there is a means of clearing this extra width so as to not show the overflow.

Edit: the extra 20% is to evenly space the columns Ruddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
.stretch-2 {
    width: 120%;
}
```

to

```
.stretch-2 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

in your CSS.

Or, put this in your css:

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I figured it had something to do with the overflow. Thanks for the quick answer, marking as correct.